# formatting of elisp file is different in emacs and other text editor

Tags: indentation, whitespace

I'm having an issue with formatting in that when I'm in emacs, the formatting looks fine:

[image]

but when the file is viewed with a different text editor, the spaces are different.

[image]

this only occurs in the `let:` form that I've defined. all the other forms seems to work okay.

Is there anything I'm missing? My emacs config is here: https://github.com/zcaudate/etude. It looks different [there](https://github.com/zcaudate/etude/blob/master/etude/global/etude-global-base.el#L150-L161) from the previous two examples.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/51214098/324105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you have `TAB` characters in your indentation (whitespace)? What happens if you use `C-u M-x untabify` on your existing code? That changes all `TAB` chars to an appropriate number of `SPC` chars.

To prevent Emacs from using `TAB` chars for indentation, you can put this in your init file:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode  nil)
```

You can check whether a given whitespace character is a `TAB` char by putting your cursor just before it and doing `C-x =`. That tells you what the character is at point.

Comment: yes it worked. thanks for that. what's the difference between setq-default and setq?

Comment: `C-h f setq-default`, `C-h f setq`. The former sets the default value for all buffers. Individual buffers can have buffer-local values of a variable.